# Android Studio - rendering of support library issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a problem with rendering of the layout preview in Android Studio, while using classes from the google support libraries (appcompat-v7, support-v4).

Example (same goes for every other element from the support libraries):

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

The libraries are added to the dependencies list of build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
}
```

The thing is, that when I change the class name in XML to `<Toolbar>` instead of `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`, everything is rendered perfectly, but it won't run on older API versions. Changing the rendering API version does not fix it, neither does changing the App Theme or building / cleaning the project.

The application runs on older and new APIs without any problems - it's just the rendering which annoys me, as I've tried everything I've found on Stack Overflow regarding such issues, and I still could not fix it. It seems to me, that the Android Studio layout renderer does not see the classes which are added in the dependency list.

Below is the code for my custom application toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                   android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:background="@color/primaryColor"
                                   app:theme="@style/CustomToolbarTheme"
    />
```

Comment: I have the same issue, none of the methods  I tried worked. Similar things happened before and were always fixed with the next update of Android Studio so let's hope..

Comment: Reinstalling Android Studio and Android SDK + starting a fresh new project did not help either. I've been fighting this problem since version 1.1 or so.. but it is good to know I'm not the only one :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answer from Nadir Williams [here](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/LNyDnnBYJ8r). He said

> Isnt the theme attribute supposed to be android:theme now instead of app:theme?

Does it help?

Comment: That is good to know, but still, it did not solve the problem.. I tested it right now with the latest Android Studio v1.2. Thank you :)